# Why the TransmitFile is not downlaoding the file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, response, transmitfile

I am downloading a file from folder but this code of me doesn't download. It doesn't throw any error but doesn't download either.

```
  Dim req As WebClient = New WebClient()
        Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
        Dim filePath As String = "~/Downloads/MyExcelFile.xls"
        response.Clear()
        response.ClearContent()
        response.ClearHeaders()
        response.Buffer = True
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Filename.extension")
        'Dim data As Byte() = req.DownloadData(Server.MapPath(filePath))
        'response.BinaryWrite(data)
        response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath))
        'response.End()
```

Comment: Does adding `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"` help? (Also, it is better to send files from an .ashx handler instead of an aspx page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
response.WriteFile("some file");
response.Flush();
response.Close();
```

also consider Andrew's response on handler type - ashx is usually cleaner, with webform you might have other things that happen during page life cycle.